# Only one of two radiobutton/checkboxes/buttons must be clicked, Laravel 5.2

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, radio-button, laravel-5

I need to add a radiobutton / checkbox / regular button / toggle / switch / slider... (don't really have a preference) to a Laravel 5.2 form. When I try radiobuttons I can select them both at the same time (not good) and I can not uncheck them (also not good).

1. The user HAS TO select one or the other.
2. Also ONLY ONE of the two choices can be selected.

Example:
In a 'start new tournament-form' the user has to choose a type: table tournament or poule tournament. Only one of the two can be chosen. When the user checks option 1, option 2 (if previously checked) will be unselected, and vice versa.

How would I achieve this? If possible pure PHP/Laravel, if not jQuery is my preference to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio button is the solution, if you want select only one use the **same name** for both radiobutton but with different value.

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="tournament">
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="poule">
```

Comment: Hmm.. indeed. Using the same name will act as only one possible choice. I learned something today (y)